# Web development using Localhost (Android phone and WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I am trying to develop a few hard coded HTML websites for mobile use, and also WordPress sites at the same time (wsing XAMPP).

The only way I know how to access a locally hosted website from mobile is connecting to the IP address of my computer which automatically connects to the "localhost" domain.

However, the local site I want to develop has the custom local domain "xx.local", whereas localhost is dedicated to my WordPress installs. e.g. localhost/wpsite

Either of these 2 fixes would be satisfying:

1. How can I install WordPress on localhost but with a different domain name e.g. wordpress.local, so that the Android site I'm testing can have the native localhost domain.

or

2. How can I access different locally hosted sites from an Android phone (instead of the IP which automatically retrieves "localhost")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2. How can I access different locally hosted sites from an android phone (instead of the IP which automatically retrieves "localhost")

If is your phone rooted (or if you are willing to root it) you can install hosts editor ([this one is my favorite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nilhcem.hostseditor&hl=en)) and the rest is pretty obvious. You add new entry with IP of your server (the machine with XAMPP installed) and the desired domain (eg: "local"). All you need to do then is to connect both machines to the same network.

*Bonus tip: if you enter just "local" to your Chrome on Android, you will be redirected to google search of word "local". You need to type "http://local" instead.*

Comment: BTW, a really cool utility you may want to check out in the future is https://browsersync.io/ -- It creates a forwarded URL accessible by any other device on the same network, and handles automatic page reloading, synchronized scrolling and clicks, and a lot more. Very handy for the exact development scenario you describe.